# Find files which are of size of x Bits

Tags: find

I want to find files which have a size of exactly x bits. However, I only know how to find files with size of x Bytes (using the find comment on *nix). How can I specify a size on bit-level?

Comment: 1 byte is usually 8 bits ... so divide your size in bits by 8 and use that with `-size`

Comment: I know no filesystem that allows file sizes with bit precision. All common ones work with full bytes. The above comment is therefore very good.